# Performance tuning: Reading servlet request body

Tags: performance, servlets, jakarta-ee

We are having a performance problem in our application - particularly when the browser client submits large volume of POST data to the server.

The bottleneck is in reading the servlet request body into a Stringbuffer - which we have observed timings above 10 seconds for large requests:  (**800 - 1400 KB**  - which, from the browsers perspective translates to anything between **800,000 - 1,500,000** characters)

```
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(2 ^ 19);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        char[] charBuffer = new char[2 ^ 19];

        for (int readCount = bufReader.read(charBuffer); readCount > -1; readCount = bufReader.read(charBuffer))
        {
            strBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, readCount);
        }
```

Some points to note:

- The 'reader' variable in the code sample above corresponds to **javax.servlet.ServletRequest** class
- Initially, the char buffer size was at **128**, and no-arg StringBuilder.
- I subsequently increased this to **2^19** to minimise the number of iterations, and resizing of the internal char buffer used by the StringBuilder for large input requests (for the examples detailed above)

Yes, I have a nagging feeling there may be greater scalability issues lurking behind this problem :-). 
However, before re-evaluating the design of the application, I would like to know whether there are any optimisations around this code block which I could try.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you 101% sure that network bandwidth and performance is excluded from being suspect? 1MB per 10 seconds is perfectly fine for clients with a 1Mbit upload cap. While clumsy and prone to character encoding problems, I don't see any inefficienties in this particular code snippet.

Comment: Yup - this performance measurement is on the server itself. Is there a better way to extract the data without the character encoding problems?

Comment: What are you doing with the String once it's all read in from the request? Would it be possible to stream it to whatever the consumer is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was glaring at me all the time...

**2 ^ 19** gets compiled into **17**  - as it is the **bitwise exclusive OR operator**, and not signed left shift :-)

There is probably a lesson to be learned here, not sure which - empirical analysis of the efficacy of peer review, or admonitions against late-night coding - I'm yet to make up my mind.

Might serve as a useful Java Puzzler though, Neal Gafter if you are reading this!

Answer (score 2):

You already have an implicit buffer thanks to `BufferedReader`, yet you're reading from that into another buffer (`char[]`) before appending to the `StringBuilder`. Just read one `char` at a time from the `BufferedReader` and append it. I believe the default buffer size for `BufferedReader` is 8K, so you can always try a different size to see if that helps. Have you inspected the amount of time being spent in GC?

Comment: I assume it's slow even with a single user so GC may not be an issue. But, multi-user loads would certainly see GC issues with 512K buffers (100 users => 50MB). Instead size for the average request.

Comment: @AngerClown - in this case, we are seeing a creep in size of the average request approch these numbers - plus these are results of tests carried out as part of projected usage patterns. *sigh* I did mention we may have scalability issues lurking beneath the surface :-)

Comment: Getting rid of the intermediate buffer will help. But, even with a 2GB heap, GC should still be pretty fast on modern hardware. So, don't worry about optimizing too much for memory until it's obvious that's your issue. My original comment was more along the lines of making sure you really needed buffers that big.